# Is there any difference between 講義 and　講演?

Tags: words

According to my dictionary both of them mean "lecture".

But is there any difference between them in nuance?

Answer (score 8):

講義 is a lecture in the sense of academia. Your college classes, etc. are 講義.

講演 is more generally the act of speaking before an audience on a certain topic, or even just *a speech* or an *address*. Note the difference in kanji. This one uses the more theatrical sense of 演 from 演じる, 演劇, 演技 etc. whereas 講義 uses the more cerebral, scholarly 義.